# Serializing compiled delegates

Tags: .net, serialization

Say that I have a class like:

```
public class Test
{
     public Func<string, bool> DoSomething { get; set; }
}
```

I have some other code that dynamically parses a string and compiles a delegate.

To set the stage, i have another application on another server that needs to execute this code so I want to serialize it and send it over the wire for execution. I could send the string that contains the information i need to recreate the delegate, but creating the delegate seems like an expensive operation seeing that I will have to repeatedly perform that operation again and again. Is there anyway to serialize that delegate?

Comment: If you serialized the delegate and then sent it again and again, it would have to be created as many times anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't that be faster than compiling the delegate from scratch?

Comment: Hard to say, and it depends what exactly creating the delegate from scratch means, but I doubt there would be a significant difference.

Comment: I suspect that the cost of compiling the delegate compared to the communication overhead would be insignificant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you worry about parsing the same string and compiling the result over and over, then you should use caching.

Just have cache implemented using something like `Dictionary<string, YourDelegate>` on the server. When you receive a string, check for it in the cache and if it's not present, create the delegate.

If the string is too long (which would mean calling `GetHashCode()`, which is used by `Dictionary`, on it would take too long), you could assign some ids or names to the delegates:

Client creates the string and a unique id for it (possibly `Guid`). It sends a message to the server saying: “here is a specification for delegate with this id”. And then another saying: “use delegate with this id”. The second message could then be called repeatedly.